# Is DB2 Server Discovery possible over a network?

Tags: database, db2

I need to discover the running db2 servers in a network.

I tried to connect to all servers in the network using the JDBC connection.  But the problem is while using JDBC, we need to specify the database name in the URL. As of now, I tried to connect to the SAMPLE database.  But if a db2 instance does not have the SAMPLE database, the connection will fail.

So I want to know the other possibilities to discover db2 servers in a network and also Is there any way to connect to the instance of the db2 server unlike connecting to a particular database(Similar to SQL - Connecting to an instance using port only)

Answer (score 1):

Db2 administration server (DAS) has the corresponding functionality. Refer to the following link:
[Discovery of administration servers, instances, and databases](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.gui.doc/doc/c0005198.html).
Note, that DAS is deprecated and may be removed in future Db2 releases.

Comment: Thanks, @Mark is there any possibility to connect to a db2 instance with drivers?

Comment: There is no documented way to use jdbc for an instance connection (attach).